# Translate JSON request to Java Google sheet API V4

Tags: java, android, python, json, google-sheets-api

In google Sheet [API guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#findreplacerequest),

I read that a `find` request (find the cell with value 'X') can be formatted as follows in JSON:

```
{
  "find": string,
  "replacement": string,
  "matchCase": boolean,
  "matchEntireCell": boolean,
  "searchByRegex": boolean,
  "includeFormulas": boolean,

  // Union field scope can be only one of the following:
  "range": {
    object(GridRange)
  },
  "sheetId": number,
  "allSheets": boolean,
  // End of list of possible types for union field scope.
}
```

requests can be made in the form of this URL
https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/spreadsheetId .......

But I'm not able to translate that to JAVA code

The closest I've found was this code in one of the forums:

```
    requests.add(new Request().setFindReplace(new FindReplaceRequest().setFind(entry.getKey())
            .setMatchEntireCell(true)
            .setMatchCase(true)
            .setReplacement(entry.getValue())
            .setRange(new GridRange()
                    .setSheetId(0)
                    .setStartRowIndex(row)
                    .setEndRowIndex(row + 1))));
}



String cellReq = (new FindReplaceRequest().setFind("samuel")).getFind();
```

which lack a response that I expect from the API, letting me know which cell in the sheet has the value I'm trying to find.

thanks

Comment: You can just send a standard http request with the api key and json string to the url and then get an answer. What has a JAVA to do with that? You want to know how to send http request with JAVA?

Comment: Thanks Peter for the answer, I just want to be consistent, and continue to use Google's libraries (Google API client, Oauth client, and the API service sheet) this takes care of Authentication and http requests and many other functions. and I see that google has a FindReplaceRequest() , but not documented enough for me to follow.

Comment: But your question is vague. I don't really understand what is the issue. You cannot "translate JSON to JAVA". JSON is data interchange language, same as XML. JAVA is a programming language. You can use JAVA to send JSON structured data via some API to get the answer. Also I do not understand what you are trying to achieve - to me it seems, that you just want an ADDRESS of cell in google sheet with the value you are searching for. Is that correct?

Comment: For JAVA Google Sheets API: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/sheets/v4 | For JAVA documentation on Google sheets API: https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/java/latest/

Comment: You're right, I didn't choose the best title. Here is a part of a JSON request to google sheets api `{ "range":" Sheet1!a2:a6 " "values": [ [ " Book "   ]  [ " Cat "   ]  [ " House "   ]  [ " Tree "   ]   ]  }`  . This request basically defines a range of cells in Google sheet to be updated, and the values to be inserted into those cells. Yes I can create a client, but I'm using google's libraries, so the above JSON will be included in the code as  .....

Comment: `String range2 = "Sheet1!A2:A6"; 
            List<List<Object>> values2 = Arrays.asList(

                    Arrays.asList(
                            "Book"
                    ), Arrays.asList(
                            "Cat"
                    ),
                    Arrays.asList(
                            "House"
                    ),
                    Arrays.asList(
                            "Tree"
                    )

                    // Additional rows ...
            );` then ....

Comment: `service.spreadsheets().values().update(spreadsheetId, range2, requestBody);` this is basically how google suggest I should do it. but when it comes to `find` thesr's no documentation. thanks again

Comment: I think that FindReplace is a method which does what it says. There is no method to return address of a cell based on a value you search for. First of all, because this can be a list of ranges! Would be hard to work with. Instead you can get the whole range you want to search in (perhaps whole sheet :) and search for the value with your JAVA code.

Comment: My question would be - what do you want to do with it when you find it? :)

Comment: So I'm trying to avoid loading a huge sheet and run an expensive client side search (which could be a cheap android phone) for a specific String. Which what I believe the JSON request above in the beginning of my question does. Yes regarding the ranges, I can see in the JSON request above that the call should specify a range; which could be a grid of cells in the sheet, a whole sheet or all sheets.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you only partially copied the example from the Guide on this page: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/batchupdate#example

You need to place the FindReplaceRequest inside a `BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest` (in the `requests` field) and send it in a `Spreadsheets.BatchUpdate` call.

The full example is:

```
List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<>();
// Change the spreadsheet's title.
requests.add(new Request()
        .setUpdateSpreadsheetProperties(new UpdateSpreadsheetPropertiesRequest()
                .setProperties(new SpreadsheetProperties()
                        .setTitle(title))
                .setFields("title")));
// Find and replace text.
requests.add(new Request()
        .setFindReplace(new FindReplaceRequest()
                .setFind(find)
                .setReplacement(replacement)
                .setAllSheets(true)));
// Add additional requests (operations) ...

BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest body =
        new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest().setRequests(requests);
BatchUpdateSpreadsheetResponse response =
        service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId, body).execute();
FindReplaceResponse findReplaceResponse = response.getReplies().get(1).getFindReplace();
System.out.printf("%d replacements made.", findReplaceResponse.getOccurrencesChanged());
```

Comment: On a second look, isn't `.setProperties(new SpreadsheetProperties()
                        .setTitle(title))
                .setFields("title")));`    meant to replace is the tile here referring the spreadsheet title and not a specific cell in the spreadsheet?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread your question as asking how to do a FindReplace in Java given the JSON, since that's what your example was.  The Sheets API does not offer a "find" option by itself, which is why you are unable to figure out how to do it.

Comment: (And the setProperties portion was just code from the example telling you how you can use BatchUpdateSpreadsheet to update a spreadsheet.  Not relevant to your goal, but useful as a general guide for how to make API calls.)

Comment: No worries, there's not much documentation there, but because of the JSON snippet in the beginning of my questions (a find and replace request), I believe the API supports `find`, and because there's a `FindReplaceRequest()` java class in the library, I got the impression that there might be some Java code that can allow find/replace. I appreciate you taking a look though.

Comment: An API doesn't have to support find in the terms you think. It can pretty easily just replace all string values in given range, without locating single cells.

Comment: I'm so super confused. Do you want to *find*, or do you want to *find+replace*.  I gave an example of how to find+replace, then you said you wanted just find, now you say you want a java example of how to find+replace (which is what my example shows?).  So color me confused.   I still think you're just asking for find, but you're probably best off restating your question and giving specific examples of what kind of input you'd expect to supply and what kind of output you'd expect back.

Comment: @SamBerlin , I would be happy to use `Find` function if there's one, the only one I see in google library is `new FindReplace().setFind(String)).getFind()` . I got the impression that your example would change the sheet title (if I have a Sheet1 and Sheet2 for example, it would change the title to Students and Classes for example) , isn't it?

Comment: @PeterMajko I'm just encourged by the fact that the library actually has a `(new FindReplace().setFind(String)).getFind()` didn't do anything for me, and I didn't find any documentation for that.

Comment: Those are just property setter and getter. :)

Comment: Correct, in https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/java/latest/com/google/api/services/sheets/v4/model/FindReplaceRequest.html  , this is how it describes what these 2 methods should do:
 `getFind
    public java.lang.String getFind()
    The value to search.
    Returns:
        value or null for none

    setFind
    public FindReplaceRequest setFind(java.lang.String find)
    The value to search.
    Parameters:
        find - find or null for none

` so getFind returns a String! when I ran it,it returned my setFind() value, not a range!!